# Mysql join where all rows meet condition; second query - where at least one row meet condition (partial match)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create two queries for orders in shop. Basically I have a order list with products. Each order could have multiple products and each product could be in storage. I want to find:

1. Orders that have all products in storage (order table joins order_products table where all found rows must have in_storage set as 1 (true/false - it's not quantity)
2. Orders that have at least one product in storage (but not all in; so joined order_products table must have at least two products where at least one is in storage; if both have in_storage set as 1 - condition is not met and won't be displayed as result)

Expected result is list on order id's  (unique/grouped).

I've created very simple version in  db fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfa2ooHt3FWmKQM9DmmPEA/0

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO orders (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO orders (id) VALUES (2);

CREATE TABLE order_products (
  id_product INT,
  id_order INT,
  in_storage INT
);
INSERT INTO order_products (id_product, id_order, in_storage) VALUES (1,1,1); # product in storage -order id 1
INSERT INTO order_products (id_product, id_order, in_storage) VALUES (2,1,0); # product not in storage - order id 1
INSERT INTO order_products (id_product, id_order, in_storage) VALUES (3,2,1); # product in storage - order id 2
INSERT INTO order_products (id_product, id_order, in_storage) VALUES (4,2,1); # product in storage - order id 2

#Query first - find orders WHERE has all products in storage 
#expected result  - order with id 2

#Query second - find orders WHERE has partial products in stronage - minimum one product marked as in_storage but not all

#expected result - order with id 1  (first product in storage; second not)

SELECT id FROM orders 
left join order_products on orders.id = order_products.id_order
where order_products.in_storage = 1
GROUP BY id
```

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Not the solution, but I noticed: "at least one is in storage" => `where order_products.in_storage > 0`

Comment: Ah i forgot to mention that in_storage it's 1/0 like true/false - it's not quantity. (it's customer database and i cannot change that idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1. You can do it by comparing the count of all orders with the count of orders in storage. If the counts are the same, all the products are in storage.

```
SELECT id
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN order_products AS op ON o.id = op.id_order
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(op.in_storage = 1)
```

#2 is the same except the counts are *not* equal. Also, add a check that the number in storage is at least 1.

```
SELECT id
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN order_products AS op ON o.id = op.id_order
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > SUM(op.in_storage = 1) AND SUM(op.in_storage) >= 1
```

In both cases you should use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`, since you're not interested in orders that have no products.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfa2ooHt3FWmKQM9DmmPEA/0)